# Reading only one character (avoiding newline), then a string (for implementing simple CLI

Tags: c, character, user-input

I need to implement a simple CLI, which will initially read one character, and then will read the 2nd, or even 3rd part of the command specified by character.

For example, these would be the commands:

```
1. p all
2. r code
3. h
4. q
```

So as you can see there are commands that need only one character and others that need a character and a string.

What I've done so far is this:
//for the character

```
char init_command;
char command[30];
while(flag) {
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &init_command, 1)
    switch(init_command)
    {
       case ('p'):
            if (fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin) == NULL)
            {
                perror("fgets print");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else
                sscanf(command, "%s", command);
            break;
       case ('h'):
           printfhelp();
           break;
       default:
           printf("Undefined command\n");
           break;
   }
}
```

I've ommitted the part of `r code` and `q` commands as it is the same.

So, what happens here is that if I type this:

> p all

Everything is ok.
But when I type this:

> h

It prints the output of printhelp() and instantly prints the undefined command message.
Now, this has to be with the \n charatcter, but I am in difficulty of correcting it.

Comment: I suggest replacing `read(STDIN_FILENO, &init_command, 1)` with `scanf(" %c", &init_command)`. The space in the format makes it skip leading whitespace, such as the left-over newline from a previous scan.

Comment: @DanielFischer: This did the trick :) Thank you very much. Also, do you know, how could I simply ignore, if the first input of the user was `print` to just read `p` and not continuing the loops to check `rint` ?

Answer (score 2):

If the `\n` is seen as "valid input", just add it to the case structures as:

```
case '\n':
  break;
```

This will allow other input to pass as error, but newlines ignored.

Comment: But I don't want to accept it :/ Because before every print, I am printing a (program_name), and now (after adding the `case '\n'`) in the case of a single character command it prints this `(program_name) (program_name) ` waiting for input. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: In that case, after you read from stdin, just add an if statement checking whether it is a newline character. If it is, ignore the printing of the program_name, else process it.

Comment: That's what I did Mr Rho, thank you! Could you check the problem I've posted as a comment at my question, to see if you could help me?

Comment: Sorry, my rep isn't high enough to answer up top, but in that case add a block of code before the case where you search for whitespace (space, \n, \r and others like \t). If the characters before that is alphanumerical, just take the first character and ignore the rest. If you start processing after the whitespace found, this should fix both your problems. In combination with the scanf you don't need to search for newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, &init_command, 1);
fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
switch(init_command)
{
   case ('p'):
            sscanf(command, "%s", command);
        break;
   case ('h'):
       printfhelp();
       break;
   default:
       printf("Undefined command\n");
       break;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your solution changes, please?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You should call fflush(stdin); after fgets. If the input is too large for the buffer, it will stay in the input stream and next call to fgets will get trash data. :)